# Java can't find class on Mac

Tags: java, classpath, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run java from the command line. I'm in the bin folder of an Eclipse project and do:

```
java nl.camilstaps.botleagues.MyGameController
```

The directory structure shows that nl/camilstaps/botleagues has a MyGameController.class file, however, I get an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class nl.camilstaps.botleagues.MyGameController
```

I looked through [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093928/4461637), but it doesn't help me.

What can be causes of this error? Yesterday it worked fine, and on an ubuntu computer with the exact same repository it also works fine (the files are synchronised with git).